# What is the default value for Union in Java for Apache Avro?

Tags: java, avro

I'm trying to set the default value for a field (using Java) and I've got a nasty exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Invalid default for field first: "Andy" not a ["null","string"]
>
> at org.apache.avro.Schema.validateDefault(Schema.java:1542)

Documentation of [Apache Avro: Unions](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Unions) says :

> Unions, as mentioned above, are represented using JSON arrays. For
>   example, ["null", "string"] declares a schema which may be either a
>   null or string.
>
> (Note that when a default value is specified for a record field whose
>   type is a union, the type of the default value must match the first
>   element of the union. Thus, for unions containing "null", the "null"
>   is usually listed first, since the default value of such unions is
>   typically null.)

Would anyone please tell me why the type of the default value must match the first element of the union ?

Answer (score 1):

seems you need change to ["string","null"] as default will be first and your default value is string.